# ActiveMQ - limit number of subcriptions

Tags: activemq-classic, activemq-artemis

I'm facing an issue where one client subscribed (by mistake) 4000+ time on the same topic (through ~100 connections). This resulted in the ActiveMQ going very low on resource and becoming very slow.

Is there some kind of mechanism to prevent this? Like one client/user could subscribe X times maximum on a topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any feature in ActiveMQ 5.x that would provide the functionality you're looking for.

However, ActiveMQ Artemis has [per-user resource limits](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/resource-limits.html). Therefore, if your broker is secured such that clients have to connect with a username and password (which it should be) then you can enforce a per-use connection limit using something like this in `broker.xml`:

```xml
<resource-limit-settings>
   <resource-limit-setting match="myUser">
      <max-connections>5</max-connections>
   </resource-limit-setting>
</resource-limit-settings>
```

It's also worth noting that when a consumer creates a subscription on a topic then a queue is created which holds all the messages for the subscription. You can limit the number of queues a user can create (and thereby the number of subscriptions) by using the `max-queues` config parameter, e.g.:

```xml
<resource-limit-settings>
   <resource-limit-setting match="myUser">
      <max-queues>3</max-queues>
   </resource-limit-setting>
</resource-limit-settings>
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. 
I looked into the documentation and concepts around Artemis ActiveMQ. 
As per my understanding, it seems that when a client subscribes to a topic, a queue is created. Therefore, the `<max-queues>` could be used to limit the number of subscription. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot Justin!